# AWS AppSync GraphQL Resolver from AWS CodeStar

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Is there a way for GraphQL resolver to resolve data source from endpoint exposed by a lambda function generated by CodeStar?

The examples provided in the AppSync docs shows how I resolve data from single lambda function, but in my case, I'm using AWS Codestar to generate a REST API using lambda, with several endpoints that returns different set of data.

For example, when I want to resolve a fetchPosts, i need to resolve it from https://my-prod-example-url/posts endpoint, not just invoke the lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on the AWS AppSync team. Http data sources are not available yet but they're very much on our roadmap.

Comment: Thanks! I can stop scratching my head and start building my own GraphQL server.